# E-mail sent from domain A on server in domain B is bounced by recipient

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, exchange, domain

I have an old Windows 2003 Enterprise Server running Microsoft Exchange. The server is in the domain networking-consultancy.com. The server hosts mail for that domain and also for two other domains, greenmountvillage.org.uk and tottington-dcs.org.uk. Mail sent from greenmountvillage.org.uk from this server is being bounced as follows:

```
"There was a SMTP communication problem with the recipient's email server.  Please contact your system administrator.
SERVER-01.networking-consultancy.com #5.5.0 smtp;554 bounce 1
recips: Denied [CS]
[fe350d75.0.2891422.00-2332.5771308.s17p02m031.mxlogic.net] (Mode:
normal)"
```

Can anyone please explain what the problem is and how to fix it?
Perhaps I should add that I am not an expert when it comes to servers. I specialised in telecommunications. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Error 554 you got usually means that message was rejected because sender's server is seen as unreliable. With additional note - fe350d75.0.2891422.00-2332.5771308.s17p02m031.mxlogic.net, it's safe to assume that recipient is using Mcafee email protection which uses their own reputation system to decide what email should or shouldn't be accepted. It's best to contact recipient and ask them to consult Mcafee support to look into this case and make adjustments.